# не видно placeholder mozilla

Tags: html, css

В мозилле не видно плейсхолдер инпута (бутстрап). Удалив этот код можно убрать проблему:

```
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Но я не могу его удалить ибо летят некоторые элементы, что делать?

Answer (score 6):

Убери свойство не со звездочки (все элементы) а с конкретного элемента.

```
.element
//вместо `element` подставь класс инпута 
{ box-sizing: content-box;}
```